# MPI_Reduce on different communicators not working as expected

Tags: c++, mpi

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <mpi.h>

using namespace std;

int ceil(int x, int y) {
    return x / y + (x % y > 0);
}

void create_group_and_comm(MPI_Group *world_group, MPI_Group *group, MPI_Comm *comm, int size, bool is_even) {
    int *ranks;
    int count = is_even ? ceil(size, 2) : size / 2;

    ranks = (int *)malloc(count * sizeof(int));

    int i = is_even ? 0 : 1, j=0; 

    while(i < size) {
        ranks[j] = i;
        j++;
        i+=2;
    }

    MPI_Group_incl(*world_group, j, ranks, group);
    MPI_Comm_create(MPI_COMM_WORLD, *group, comm);

    free(ranks);
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int size, rank, *result_odd, *result_even;
    int rank_gr;
    char processor_name[MPI_MAX_PROCESSOR_NAME];
    MPI_Status status;
    MPI_Comm  even_comm, odd_comm;
    MPI_Group even_group, odd_group, world_group;

    int *A, *Rows;
    int namelen;
    MPI_Init(&argc, &argv);
    MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &size);
    MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &rank);
    MPI_Get_processor_name(processor_name, &namelen);

    if (rank == 0)
    {
        A = (int *)malloc(size * size * sizeof(int));

        for (int i = 0; i < size * size; i++) {
                A[i] = rand() / 1000000;
        }
       
        printf("Initial data:\n");
        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
        {
            
            putchar('|');

            for (int j = 0; j < size; j++)
                printf("%.4d ", A[i*size+j]);

            printf("|\n");
        }

        MPI_Barrier(MPI_COMM_WORLD);
    }
    else
        MPI_Barrier(MPI_COMM_WORLD);

    MPI_Comm_group(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &world_group);

    create_group_and_comm(&world_group, &even_group, &even_comm, size, true);
    create_group_and_comm(&world_group, &odd_group, &odd_comm, size, false);

    Rows = new int[size];
    MPI_Scatter(A, size, MPI_INT, Rows, size, MPI_INT, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);

    result_odd = new int[size];
    result_even = new int[size];

    if(rank % 2 == 0) {
        MPI_Reduce(Rows,result_even,size,MPI_INT,MPI_MAX,0,even_comm);
    } else {
        MPI_Reduce(Rows,result_odd,size,MPI_INT,MPI_MIN,0,odd_comm);
    }

    if(rank == 0) {
        printf("Max values for columns on even:\n");
        for(int idx = 0; idx < size;idx++) {
            printf("Column %d: %d\n", idx+1, result_even[idx]);
        }
        printf("Max values for columns on odd:\n");
        for(int idx = 0; idx < size;idx++) {
            printf("Column %d: %d\n", idx+1, result_odd[idx]);
        }
    }

    //MPI_Comm_free(&even_comm);
    //MPI_Comm_free(&odd_comm);
    MPI_Group_free(&even_group);
    MPI_Group_free(&odd_group);
    MPI_Finalize();
    return 0;
}
```

Hello i'm writing an application using MPI library, i'm trying to create 2 groups with each of them with their own communicator. Basically one group which holds processors with rank even calculates the maximum value per column using MPI_Reduce between them(processors in group), and the second one calculates the minimum for each column in matrice. For even rank MPI_Reduce works as expected but for processors with odd rank is not working as it should, can someone help me what i'm doing wrong? Below is a picture with the problem i described:
[image here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wda38.png)

Comment: Rank 0 is not part of `odd_comm`, so `result_odd` does not contain the result of the reduction (it is on rank 1). Note `MPI_Comm_split()` is way simpler to create the odd/even communicators.

Comment: Thanks for your response, i will take into consideration to use MPI_Comm_split in the feature :)

Comment: (nice) pun intended?